# Parse - multiple condition queries issue in xcode (objective-c)

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I'm using the parse backend to be database of my apps in Xcode (objective-c), but I don't know how to write a multiple condition parse format query. I want to convert the below query to a parse format query in the Xcode.

```
$msg_record = $this->db->query('SELECT msg, send_id, send_time FROM msg_record
                     WHERE (send_id=123456789 AND to_id=987654321) OR (send_id=987654321 AND to_id=123456789)
                     ORDER BY send_time ASC')->result();
```

Can anybody help me to convert the query? Thanks.

Comment: Did u check with Parse Compound Query

Comment: I already read it. I can write "WHERE send_id=123456789 AND to_id=987654321" parse query, but I don't know how to write with two big conditional using OR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create an *or* condition in a Parse query, you will have to make two (or more) subqueries which you merge with the `orQueryWithSubqueries`.
Be aware that you cannot translate `SELECT` directly from SQL to Parse.

This is what you are looking for:

```
PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"msg_record"];
[query1 whereKey:@"send_id" equalTo:@"123456789"];
[query1 whereKey:@"to_id" equalTo:@"987654321"];

PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"msg_record"];
[query2 whereKey:@"send_id" equalTo:@"987654321"];
[query2 whereKey:@"to_id" equalTo:@"123456789"];

PFQuery *mainQuery = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[query1,query2]];
[mainQuery orderByAscending:@"send_time"];
```